# DDD - where to put Query logic?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Good morning,

Apologies if this question has been answered in DDD resources, but I haven't been able to "google" the answer.

I understand and like the idea of separating queries and commands, commands being the ones that retrieve the domain object and potentially change its state. And it makes sense for queries to follow a separate code-path to the commands, i.e. retrieving information directly from the repository, and not via the domain object, especially considering one might want to retrieve thousands of parts of a domain object for a view (you wouldn't want to necessarily bring back all the objects, for only a few fields).

However, considering the following object, where its state depends on internal domain (i.e. business) logic:

```
internal class MyContrivedClass
{
  public bool IsOpen { get; private set; }
  public bool DueDate { get; private set; }

  public bool IsOverdue()
  {
    if(IsOpen)
    {
      return DueDate < DateTime.Now
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }  
}
```

If I want to show a list of `MyContrivedClass` objects, that includes whether the object is overdue (plus some other fields), I have a couple of options:

- bring back all the objects, and execute the method `IsOverdue`.
- send a simple query to the database (via the repo/context) and check the DueDate against today's date and whether the object is "Open"

However, I see problems with both those approaches. The first approach might bring back thousands of huge objects, which would be very inefficient. The second approach repeats the `IsOverdue` logic - if it changes, I'll have to change it in the query and the domain object.

One solution I've thought of is to have a static method in the domain object, e.g.:

```
internal class MyContrivedClass
{
  public bool IsOpen { get; private set; }
  public bool DueDate { get; private set; }

  public static bool IsOverdue(DateTime dueDate, bool isOpen)
  {
    if(isOpen)
    {
      return dueDate < DateTime.Now
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public bool IsOverdue()
  {
    return IsOverdue(DueDate, IsOpen);
  }    
}
```

Now, the query can call the static method, once it's retrieved the relevant fields. So, if the `IsOverdue` logic changes, the query will still need to change, but it would be obvious, because there'd be a compiler error. And any commands that cause a check of `IsOverdue` operate as before.

My question is, are there any standard patterns for this? other than exposing the required logic via static methods?

Many thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use the [Specification Pattern](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/specification-pattern-c-implementation/#:%7E:text=Specification%20pattern%20is%20a%20pattern,parts%20of%20the%20code%20base.&text=And%20of%20course%2C%20we%20can,to%20the%20method%20as%20well.).
With that pattern you will externalize the "IsOverdue" logic to an external component (called Specification) and it will be usable in your current object but also directly in a EF query (thanks the lambda expression).

Some says a specification is only needed when you need to validate and query something with the same rule so it seems to fit in your case :-)

EDIT : By the way (and it's pity) but the specification pattern cannot be used with encapsulated model so if your fields are private the specification (which is an external class) will not be able to do anything... In that case you would have to push the CQRS concept further and having a specific table where the "IsOverdue" field would be already computed, making your query ignorant about the logic. That specific table could be filled at the same time, or per batch, or per event...

Comment: very interesting - thank you. Essentially extracting the logic in the static into a Specification. Makes things a bit more abstract, but could be quite powerful.

Comment: thinking about it a bit more - actually, for the Specification pattern, I'd still need to pass in the whole `MyContrivedClass` object - unless I've missed something?

Comment: It's quite powerful. Especially because it can be used in memory and with an ORM. And also it's really useful to chain them to build bigger specification based on smaller ones.
And yes, you need to pass the whole object.

Comment: Why exposing static method is better? If your specification needs the whole object from DB it will be the same for your static method. 

And why having a specification will duplicate the logic? If you're using specification the query/validation logic should only be in there.

And in the end: in DDD you should always get the whole object... Even the whole aggregate to be accurate. 
Since in DDD an aggregate is considered as a whole, you should always get it entirely to take a decision. And yes it's not perfomant, that's why CQRS exists, to optimize the reading part.

Comment: I am talking about the reading side of things. If I'm updating an object, then yes, I'll retrieve the whole object (or aggregate) from the repo, and update it. But for a query, why should I get the whole object, when most of the object isn't needed? Retrieving thousands of instances of the object for a query hits performance too hard.

I can't see another way aside from exposing the rule as a static method on the domain object, the parameters of which are all that's required to execute the rule - then the rule can be used for commands and all queries.

Comment: Obivously in CQRS you normally would have a specialized view for reading things. By example you would have a field IsOverdue containing true/false so no need to apply any logic since the value is already computed. 
Why having the full object? Let's say you have a product management. Each product contains many dates (creation date, expiration date, last check date, ...) and you create a specification to determine if it still good or not for consumption. If you're specification accept the whole object it's easy but if it accept a DateTime, how the user will not which one he needs to provide?

Comment: But the good news is, depending on the implementation of the specification, it can be run directly on database ! :-) If your specification can return a lambda expression it can be used directly by your ORM (EF for example). 
So you specification can be ran in memory (and you need to retrieve the whole object) or you can use the generated expression with your ORM that will be convert into SQL. So no need to retrieve to whole graph.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldn't have a field, IsOverdue, as it's state changes depending on the date, so the result must be computed at the time of the query. The static method would be expecting parameters that are named the same as the fields in the object, so that should clear up confusion, but I'm not too fond of exposing lots of static methods on the domain object. Now, the Specification returning a lambda runnable by the ORM is interesting! That would mean the logic could be encapsulated and it wouldn't require retrieving the whole object. I will certainly look into that - thanks.